# How do I subscribe to all questions in my team?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

We recently created a Stack Overflow for Teams instance, and I was wondering if I could subscribe to ALL questions in my team? I can see how to subscribe to tags, but am unsure if there is a way to subscribe to everything - especially because we will be making multiple tags while using the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great question! That functionality doesn't exist yet. BUT, we're interested in building that feature. In fact, it's something that I personally want as well. I don't have a precise timeline, but know it's something we're working towards.

In the meantime, there are some other features that might be slightly helpful to your cause:

- **Slack Integration** - If you have configured the slack integration you can select "questions" and "all tags" and then select your own DM as the destination and you'll receive notification for all new questions there
- **Newsletter** - We have a weekly newsletter configured to send you updates on new questions. But, that's not nearly as *timely*.

Anyhow, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Don't you guys have an rss feed for /new?

Comment: @Braiam Not for Teams since the data is private.

Comment: Cool, thanks - we use Microsoft Teams instead of Slack - are there other integrations / hooks for integration going to be available? And should this be a different question?

Comment: We haven't planned a Microsoft Teams integration yet @CarterMusick, but we do have an API available (and haven't done an awesome job of surfacing it yet) which can be found here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/channels and also pay close attention to the authentication section here https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication